# Angularjs filter through objectarray of objects

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to filter an array of objects by another object, and show them if they have as a property either one of the second object's entries.

My array of objects to filter:

```
accounts = [
   0: {id: 24, name: 'name24', company: company1, location:location1, ...}
   1: {id: 25, name: 'name25', company: company2, location:location1, ...}
   2: {id: 26, name: 'name26', company: company1, location:location2, ...}
   3: {id: 27, name: 'name27', company: company3, location:location1, ...}
   4: {id: 28, name: 'name28', company: company2, location:location3, ...}
   ..................................................
]
```

My filtering object:

```
companies = {
   company1: 1,
   company2: 0,
   company3: 1,
   ............
}
```

In my `companies` object, I have all the companies with a value of `1` for `selected` and `0` for `not selected`.

I already have a filter for the location, but `data.locations` contains only one entry.

```
<div class="description">
   <div ng-repeat="accounts in data.accounts | filter:{location_id: data.location.id">....</div>
</div>
```

More clearly, I want to filter and get the accounts that belong to `companies` which have the value of `1` in my `companies` object if it's possible with a method like the one I use for filtering the location, without creating a custom filter.

Comment: `companies` is not the correct array.

Comment: @Rahul, but why is that?

Comment: is that array like [1,0,1] or with `=`?

Comment: @RahulSharma, i use the company name as key and 1 or 0 as the value.

Comment: You can't do that in the array, That should be an object. `{ company1:1}`

Comment: @RahulSharma, thank you for that, edited.